# Summer of Tag Cleanup Project

Tags: discussion

This idea has been floating about The DMZ for some time now.

> [I think we need a Summer of Tag Cleanup project...](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10031025#10031025)

I think this is a great idea so here is a meta post to start the ball rolling. I know it's not really summer anymore but hell, I can't think of a catchier name.....

For starters, we will need community members to identify the tags we should improve upon. This might include things like missing tag wiki excerpts and description, duplicate tags as  well as ambiguous tags.

If you do spot a tag that we could improve upon, please write an answer stating the name of the tag as well as how it should be improved upon.

[image: Trogdor]

Comment: Summer? It's not even summer in Australia yet.

Comment: And burnination has forsaken the countryside!

Comment: Our tags of course, should be variations of [Steve, Stevie, Steven, Stevo](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlanetOfSteves). This will save effort on tag descriptions. The default tag if no suitable tag exists should of course be `Marklar`.

Answer (score 3):

[protection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protection) - kill it with fire