# Usefulness of an "Information" tag usage on Information Security SE?

Tags: discussion, tags

We are on *Information* Security SE, and I just saw a post showing this strange [information](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/information) tag.

When looking at the other 28 posts having this tag, they are dealing with various subjects as viruses, cryptography, password policies, compliance and even career!

I have quite a hard time to find the link between all these posts (unless that people seek some information on the requested subject!), and the blank wiki summary does not help.

I saw that @Avid [already mentioned](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/the-great-2015-tag-cleaning/1765?s=1%7C0.3945#1765) as part of the 2015 tag cleaning, but did not found any further information.

Does this tag have some use? Is its deletion pending?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well spotted. There are a handful of tags, like this one, that keep popping up.

Feel free to edit it off from those posts, and we'll remove it again

Comment: Maybe I should ask this as a new question, but is there a way to edit it off without raising all the concerned post back on top of the active posts?

Comment: Sadly, no there isn't. Edits will bump to the top. Which is why when we go on major tag clearouts we do them in batches :-)

Comment: Done, 0 post using this tag anymore.

Comment: Well, that's the better part of the front page...

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf If a tag is present on a large number of questions, and there is a consensus on meta that the tag should be removed, a Stack Exchange employee can delete the tag directly from the database (it's called “[burnination](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag)”).