# Can we merge [session] and [session-management]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I think AviD made the case very well a year ago as an answer to [a now closed meta question](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1892/98538):

> There are separate tags for [session](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/session) and [session-management](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/session-management).
>
> This seems incredibly redundant, I cannot imagine a situation that should be tagged with "session" but not "session-management"...

If you don't agree, pick 10 random questions from each tag, mix them, and try to see if you can tell them apart.

Preferably session-management should be a synonym of session, but I do not have enough points to suggest the synonym.

Comment: Perhaps a moderator can wield the mighty merge hammer?

Comment: Agreed - will do

Comment: @RoryAlsop [The dead are walking the earth!](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/session)